# How do I unlock "/var/lib/apt/lists/"?

Tags: package-management, apt

I was installing an item using package manager when it froze. I used <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to close it.

Afterwards, whenever I try to install anything via `apt-get`, the terminal reads:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

How do I unlock `/var/lib/apt/lists/`?