# Cannot install g++ because packages g++, libqt4-opengl, and libqt4-svg have unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation, compiling, g++

While trying to compile a program with the following command:

```
g++ -o <output_file> <my_file.cpp>
```

I found the following report....

```
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Then I tried...

```
nawshad@ubuntu:~/Thesis/Codes/Thesis_Utility_Function/Test Codes$ sudo apt-get   install   g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-4.6 (>= 4.6.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-opengl : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libqt4-svg : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I can't install due to unmet dependencies.

---

While updating, the following error occurs:

```
nawshad@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nawshad:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

---

I followed the instructions at [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15433/955434)), but the unmet dependencies are still not resolved.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: If [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/175581/22949) didn't solve this (or for anyone for whom it didn't), I suspect this is actually a duplicate of [Problem installing g++ ccompiler on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/514384/problem-installing-g-ccompiler-on-ubuntu-14-04), since the indicated qt packages really shouldn't be dependencies of `g++` at all, suggesting `g++` may be being interpreted as a pattern by `apt-get` (which happens when the package manager doesn't know about the existence of a package called `g++` due to repositories being disabled).

Answer (score 7):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You should always run that before installing or upgrading packages on the command-line (unless you've run it very recently). It fetches information about what packages are available in what versions from where.

You may simply be able to install `g++` now, but go ahead and do as Web-E says (after running the above command), to fix any currently broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

(The `-f` can actually go before or after the `install`; the effect is the same.)

Then try installing `g++` again:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

If that still fails, please **edit your question** to show any error messages (and *also* the output of the above two commands when you ran them). But it should succeed.

Comment: while updating following error occurs:
nawshad@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nawshad: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK Do you have other open package management programs, like the Update Manager, the Software Center, Synaptic, or another running instance of `apt-get`? (Also, in the future, to share output from the command-line, you should **edit your question**; usually it is very difficult to read it without proper formatting, which it almost never has when posted in a comment.)

Comment: Sorry, I am very new in this group, I'll edit my question at later comments, yes I do have, its Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK Quit the Software Center and try running those commands again. This should eliminate the `Could not get lock` errors.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK If the problem still of the lock still exists, try taking a look at [How do I unlock /var/lib/apt/lists ?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102054/how-do-i-unlock-var-lib-apt-lists)

Comment: Now,after updating, I ran the above commands serially, but the unmet dependencies are not resolved.

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK Please try Steps 1-5 of [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure). That may solve your problem. If not, please *edit your question* to provide all the text from the Terminal, from Step 5.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thank you guy.. Your answer was very useful for me