# How can I know that I have g++ installed in my ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, c++, g++

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 . I tried to run a c++ code by a command like this:

```
g++ first.cpp -o first
```

Then it said:

```
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install g++
```

And then I did. After typing it and pressing enter it showed a message like this:

```
gedit is already the newest version.
libgrail6 is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-core is already the newest version.
libgdata13 is already the newest version
...
```

(and many more lines like this)

Then I tried to run the same command given above again. But the terminal said again that I don't have g++ installed. What am I missing here? How to run the C++ code now?

Comment: Packages `sudo apt-get install g++` selected--`gedit` and so forth--aren't dependencies of `g++` and shouldn't be listed. Thus `apt-get`'s matching `g++` as a pattern (a regular expression) a package name. (Actually, it might be matching the first `+` as part of a regexp and the second as special APT syntax, I'm not sure.) This doesn't normally happen when trying to install `g++`; when it does, it means *it does not know a package whose exact name is `g++` actually exists.* [The solution is here.](http://askubuntu.com/q/514384) (c.f. [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/175571)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To find out what compilers are installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

`dpkg --list | grep compiler`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Type "gcc" in terminal  and then press Tab in your keyboard,the versions of gcc that are installed,will be shown.
good luck

Comment: Isn't it possible for `gcc` to be installed without `g++`? (Or for some versions of `gcc` to be installed without the corresponding versions of `g++`?)

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential